# insert error in sqlserver 2005 using with asp.net MVC 1.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2005

how this error can be removed

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Address_ContactPerson". The conflict occurred in database "C:\USERS\SAHIL\DOCUMENTS\DOWNLOADS\COMPRESSED\N-LAYERDESIGN\N-LAYERDESIGN\APP_DATA\NLAYER.MDF", table "dbo.ContactPerson", column 'Id'.

pls help?

Answer (score 0):

This error can be avoided by either respecting the foreign key constraint or removing this constraint in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The `ContactPersonId` in your `Address` table doesn't have a matching record in your `ContactPerson` table.

Make sure the `ContactPerson` is added first.

Comment: Then your inserting a different `ContactPersonId` into your `Address` table. Or you have two `ContactPerson` tables.

Comment: Are you sure the `ContactPersonId` you are adding to the `Address` table corresponds to an existing `ContactPerson` with the same `id`?

Answer (score 0):

From the name (FK_Address_ContactPerson) and error it seems like your contact doesn't have an address.

Are you trying to insert a contact where the  there is an invalid value in the the address id on the contact, but  where the corresponding Address doesn't exist?

Comment: From the name I assumed the opposite? FK_tablename_column ? Although it seems backwards